# Combine two programs in terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm running Ubuntu and I have 2 executables. One of them is a sorting algorithm which uses scanf to read the input. I also have a `generate` executable that generates n random numbers.
How can I make that the output of `generate` generates the arguments for the sorting algorithm.

For example I would do

```
./bubble     // bubblesort implementation
1
5
2
3
4
CTRL+D       // to stop the reading
```

and the output is the list of numbers sorted. I also can do

```
./generate 10
```

and it will give me 10 random numbers.
I want that the `./bubble` input is the `./generate` output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the stdout from one program into the stdin of another program using [unix pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

```
./generate 10 | ./bubble
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called `xargs`!

To treat the output of `generate` as arguments, you can do that:

```
./generate 10 | xargs ./bubble
```

If you want to write to `bubble`s stdin, try this:

```
./bubble <( ./generate 10 )
```